# What software caused my MacBook to panic reboot?

Tags: high-sierra, kernel-panic

My MacBook Pro running High Sierra spontaneously rebooted while I was moving the mouse using Chrome as focus to access GMail.

Upon reboot I got this panic report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       77844606-CC97-41AA-EDF6-B18C43EFEB66

Tue Jan  2 18:42:49 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff7fab07731f): "IOAccelResource::free called for resource still owned by an IOAccelShared"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IOAcceleratorFamily_kexts/IOAcceleratorFamily-376.6/Kext2/IOAccelResource.cpp:247
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff821509b690 : 0xffffff802a0505f6 
0xffffff821509b6e0 : 0xffffff802a17d604 
0xffffff821509b720 : 0xffffff802a16f0f9 
0xffffff821509b7a0 : 0xffffff802a002120 
0xffffff821509b7c0 : 0xffffff802a05002c 
0xffffff821509b8f0 : 0xffffff802a04fdac 
0xffffff821509b950 : 0xffffff7fab07731f 
0xffffff821509b970 : 0xffffff7fab120311 
0xffffff821509b9e0 : 0xffffff7fab1206ac 
0xffffff821509ba30 : 0xffffff7fab096196 
0xffffff821509ba80 : 0xffffff7fab095fa4 
0xffffff821509bac0 : 0xffffff7fab095206 
0xffffff821509bb00 : 0xffffff802a6b9038 
0xffffff821509bb50 : 0xffffff7fab11e5ce 
0xffffff821509bb70 : 0xffffff802a6c1e47 
0xffffff821509bcb0 : 0xffffff802a129844 
0xffffff821509bdc0 : 0xffffff802a055c30 
0xffffff821509be10 : 0xffffff802a032cbd 
0xffffff821509be60 : 0xffffff802a045b7b 
0xffffff821509bef0 : 0xffffff802a15952d 
0xffffff821509bfa0 : 0xffffff802a002926 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(376.6)[5F8F39B4-41AB-3263-9867-D0FAF9BBD2AE]@0xffffff7fab062000->0xffffff7fab0f7fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[58669FC2-CC90-3594-AD69-DB89B923FD20]@0xffffff7fab031000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(209.2.2)[AE58720D-7079-388F-AD95-FD2366F98F8D]@0xffffff7fab046000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[C08F7FC1-78A4-3A1B-BFE2-C07080CF2048]@0xffffff7faa894000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(517.22)[2AEA02BF-2A38-3674-A187-E5F610FD65B7]@0xffffff7faac1b000
         com.apple.GeForce(10.2.8)[3ADA09ED-A1B5-3DA9-B39C-1833B5803638]@0xffffff7fab108000->0xffffff7fab1a2fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[C08F7FC1-78A4-3A1B-BFE2-C07080CF2048]@0xffffff7faa894000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(517.22)[5672A7EF-44E8-3897-90DE-DAF4C1488143]@0xffffff7faac6f000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.2.8)[39AC3832-2295-3B7B-85F6-F69D66D46EC7]@0xffffff7faac8c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(517.22)[2AEA02BF-2A38-3674-A187-E5F610FD65B7]@0xffffff7faac1b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(376.6)[5F8F39B4-41AB-3263-9867-D0FAF9BBD2AE]@0xffffff7fab062000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
17C88

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.3.0: Thu Nov  9 18:09:22 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.31.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 87641697-A3DD-30C4-B010-E65ECE57550B
Kernel slide:     0x0000000029c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8029e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8029d00000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 524188984731443
last loaded kext at 506324468178265: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm   5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fad87d000, size 49152)
last unloaded kext at 506631470885614: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fad868000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.sophos.nke.swi  9.6.50
com.sophos.kext.oas 9.6.51
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.14
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.14
com.intel.driver.EnergyDriver   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   92
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.24
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   280.12
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.16.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.GeForce   10.2.8
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.3.0
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.16.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.16.21
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  254
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.31.8
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.30.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1220.18.1a2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.IOBufferCopyEngineTest    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  203
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   203
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1204.13
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1201.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 280.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.2.8
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.16.2
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   517.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.16.21
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    376.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   209.2.2
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.16.21
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    517.22
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 261
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.6.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.20.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBufferCopyEngineFamily    1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.30.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    650.5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCRTC    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00F2.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.16.1a2)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.2f2, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Is there any clue in there what went wrong or what program caused the issue?

Comment: Check whether you are [or were] eligible for this recall - https://www.apple.com/ca/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Comment: Same problem here on 10.13.2 (and before that on 10.13.1), MacBookPro11,3, external 4k monitor via mini-DP cable, no external GPU

Comment: Twice in the last 24 hours on 10.13.4, MacBookPro11,3, external Thunderbolt monitor plus an old 27" iMac as a second monitor via mini-DP.

Answer (score 3):

From my perspective, this is a bug in Apple's code and you can't do anything about it, other than updating whenever a new version of macOS is released. This instability has surfaced on my stable MacBook Pro 15" Late 2013 after the upgrade to macOS High Sierra.

Just make sure you send the crash reports to Apple and some day, somewhere in the future they will fix it (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, it seems like your MacBook has some sort of conflict with 3D acceleration (accelerator tried to use resource that is currently used). You seem to have an external GPU, so try removing it. If that still doesn't work, you might have to reinstall your system or restore from backup, because it is possible that your system files are damaged.

Comment: I do not have any external graphics card, I am using an external monitor though through the external firewire port to a Mac branded device that converts to dual-DVI that drives the monitor and is power driven with USB.